# List Item Name not populating - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, splistitem, splist, csv

I have a PowerShell script that outputs to a CSV file all items from all Lists and all files from all Document Libraries in a Site shown below:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts/HTG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
}


Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewOutput.csv
```

Below is a sample of what this script outputs:

[image]

In the output shown above Arc Items, Archived Stuff, and Boats are the names of Lists. On the other hand, Content Affiliate and Cross References are the names of Document Libraries. My problem is that the script outputs only Item Names from Document Libraries and not Lists. What line should I add in order to output Item Names from Lists as well? In other words, how can I display the names of items contained in a List? Can someone please assist?

Comment: A list item isn't going to have an $item.File.Name. For a list, you'd probably want to do $item["Title"] or $item["ID"]

Comment: I'm assuming with that being done it will return item names from Lists but then return blank Item Names for Document Libraries right? How can I display Item Names for both Lists and Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Eric Alexander as I have figured it out with some direction from you. I have found also that by changing this line:

```
"Item Name" = $item.File.Name
```

To:

```
"Item Name" = $item.Name
```

That it returns both list names and file names from Doc Libraries as well. I tried what you posted but some Item Names returned blank. Not sure of what the reason was.